# Remove all text after text string

Tags: r, excel, replace, character

I have an R data frame and an Excel spreadsheet (created from the data frame) where I have NCAA basketball play-by-play data. In a column, there may be a string

"Wesley Harris made Three Point Jumper. Assisted by Jevon Carter.".

I would like to delete everything after and including the phrase "Assisted by", but neither in R nor Excel have I found a way to do this. Note that not every entry has the phrase "Assisted" so I have to account for this as well.

Comment: "not every entry has the phrase "Assisted" so I have to account for this as well" - do you just leave those entries as-is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using excel equations `LEFT` & `SEARCH`

> A1 = LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Assisted",A1&"Assisted")-1)

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In R, we can use `regexpr` to find out the character number of where "Assisted by" is in the string.  Then we can just take the substring from character 1 to the character before the start of "Assisted by":

```
mystr <- "Wesley Harris made Three Point Jumper. Assisted by Jevon Carter."

A <- regexpr("Assisted by", mystr)[[1]]
substr(mystr, start=1, stop=A-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed to post-processing this in excel using vba, it might be easiest to convert the string into an array and use "Assisted" as the delimiter and just get the first part, like so (assume string is in `A1`):

```
Cells(1,1)=Split(Cells(1,1), "Assisted")(0)
```

If you need to do this for every cell in column A, you could loop through it with

```
with Worksheets("Sheet1")
for i=1 to .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    .Cells(i,1)=Split(.Cells(i,1), "Assisted")(0)
next i
end with
```